# What are the names, charges, and masses, and spins of the 6 new particles proposed in the SMASH standard model of elementary particles?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, standard-model, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

As you may know, 6 new particles have been proposed to solve a few of the standard model's problems. However, after much of research, I was unable to find the exact names (of the color triplet fermion, and the right-handed neutrinos), as well as their masses, spins and charges (of all the proposed particles).

I'm aware that the [research paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01639) is available, but it was too advanced for me to understand (and too long). I'm just a science enthusiast who's intent upon creating a good-looking and informative standard model, and I'd like to include the Standard Model-Axion-Seesaw-Higgs (SMASH) particles in it.

Comment: What you are searching for is more or less provided in the pictures and text here:
https://www.desy.de/news/news_search/index_eng.html?openDirectAnchor=1176

Comment: @AlmostClueless the pictures on the website have only a few of the names, and mass/charge of the particles.

Comment: You wont find any masses, since these extra particles are not yet observed. Also there is AFAIK no "name" for the particles arising from the $\rho$ and $Q$ fields.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Their first paper](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1482635) was in 2017.

They have this review paper( April 2019), calling their proposal *SMASH from SM-Axion-Seesaw-Higgs* .

> [Several Problems](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1729237) in Particle Physics and Cosmology Solved in One SMASH

> Guillermo Ballesteros(
> Madrid, IFT and Madrid, Autonoma U.
> )
> , Javier Redondo(
> Zaragoza U. and Munich, Max Planck Inst.
> )
> , Andreas Ringwald(
> DESY
> )
> , Carlos Tamarit(
> Munich, Tech. U.
> )

, there exists a link to the pdf, 2019.

> Abstract: (Frontiers)
> The Standard Model (SM) of particle physics is a big success. However, it lacks explanations for cosmic inflation, the matter-anti-matter asymmetry of the Universe, dark matter, neutrino oscillations, and the feebleness of CP violation in the strong interactions. The latter may be explained by a complex scalar field charged under a spontaneously broken global U(1) Peccei- Quinn (PQ) symmetry. Moreover, the pseudo Nambu-Goldstone boson of this breaking -the axion- may play the role of the dark matter. Furthermore, the modulus of the PQ field is a candidate for driving inflation. If additionally three extra SM singlet neutrinos (whose mass is induced by the PQ field) are included, the five aforementioned problems can be addressed at once. We review the SM extension dubbed SMASH –for SM-Axion-Seesaw-Higgs portal inflation–, discuss its predictions and tests in astrophysics, cosmology, and laboratory experiments. Variants of SMASH are also considered and commented on.

So from the abstract, three of them are neutrinos, and the others gosldstone bosons and axions. In the review article this is how they name the particles, Thw N are the new neutrinos:

[image: smash]

[From the list of the Inspire site](https://inspirehep.net/authors/1051733),  there are about 300 citations to the papers,  so the proposal has not taken the community by storm and has not been adopted so as to give further names to the new proposals. Maybe it is too soon.At the moment there are no unexplained particles with data up to now. Maybe for future colliders there will be an interest to check for the smash particles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I want to note that the Inspire list is for the first author  in the list of authors, which seems to be in alphabetical order.