# What would a standard model that incorporates the SMASH particles look like?

Tags: standard-model, higgs, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm trying to create a standard model which incorporates the SMASH (Standard Model Axion Seesaw Higgs portal inflation) particles, but I'm having a hard time doing it because I'm unable to find as many resources. For one, I'm unsure of where these 6 new particles should be positioned, and what category they would fall into. I categorized the color-triplet fermion as a Quark (not sure if this is right), and the 3 right-handed neutrinos as leptons. This standard model from phys.org helped a bit:

[image]

And this is what I came up with:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is right, so I would appreciate any help as to categorizing and positioning these new particles.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are attempting to organize them, if they physics community actually finds enough evidence to include them on the table, then such a table will come out eventually. There are more factors that have to be thought of, for instance while the sterile neutrinos are fermions, they only interact gravitationally and not via any of the other SM forces so placing them with the neutrinos might not be the best place for them.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602751/2451

Comment: What exactly does “create a standard model” mean to you?

Comment: @G.Smith I'm just creating my own standard model. It's not like I'm re-arranging and categorizing it, I'm re-making it with what I feel are better aesthetics.